# Remove outside color of rectangle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I am making a logo by using a rectangular shape, i.e. rectangular shape > color > pentool > ***shapes from outside the rectangular shapes and colored it*** > complete > merge.

Now I want to remove the outside color and everything if there. How can I delete everything from the outside? 
.[image]

Comment: Hi salman, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. What do you mean with 'outside colour'? Could you please clraify what you want to achieve? Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Make Clipping Mask. Don't recall in your older version of Photoshop but try:

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and mouse click between Shape 2 and Shape 1 in the layer panel. Assuming that made it a clipping mask (an arrow will appear by the thumbnail) then go up the layers doing the same.

If that didn't work then make each a clipping mask through the menu system.

Comment: Clipping mask works exactly the same in cs3 as in the most current version (excluding folder clipping mask that was introduced in cs6, I think).